# SVN in Eclipse: Cannot commit certain folders

Tags: eclipse, svn

I'm using SVN within Eclipse. Whenever I change a file I commit the changes. It works for everything except for three certain folders (which contain certain files) I cannot commit. When trying to commit them I receive the following error message:

[image]

`workspace\yp\src\yp\forum\locale\cs` is one of the three uncommitable folders. The folder definitely doesn't exist on the server yet, but I get the above error each time I'm trying to upload it.

How do I solve the problem?

**EDIT:** I've deleted the `.svn` folders from the problematic directories. I still get the same error when trying to commit and the problematic directories have no `.svn` folders.

**EDIT:** I'm still trying to fix the problem. Now I get another error message when trying to commit:

[image]

**EDIT:** Now I've tried to do `Team --> Cleanup` and got that error message:

[image]

Comment: Did you try removing your entire project in Eclipse and checking it out again?

Comment: Yes. Did it. Still same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the problematic folders out of the way, then do `Team->Update` which will recreate the folders from the repository.

Then you can copy your changed files back.

This problem can arise when there are files in a folder checked into the repository that only differ in *case* - which is not supported in Windows. So it might be worthwile to look at the repository with a repository browser - if it is `http://` then the web browser will do.

Answer (score 0):

try deleting .svn folder in your pc and try adding folder or file again.

Comment: Thanks. But id didn't work. I've deleted all the .svn folders in my problematic directories and I get the same error message when trying to commit. It doesn't recreate new .svn folders again. So now there are no .svn folders in the problematic directories. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Extract your project from SVN to a new folder.

Erase all sourcecode files ( something like any file but .svn ) and replace with the ones from your previous working folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try Team/Cleanup in Eclipse (right click in Project explorer or Navigator)

Comment: When trying to cleanup I get another error message: "'C:\Users\yonatan\python workspace\yp\src\yp\forum\locale' is not a working copy directory"